# Are countries owned?

Tags: ownership, incorporation

I'm trying to understand something.

Businesses in the United States have one or more owners, correct?

That said a business is an entity.  A corporation is a person owned by many persons called Shareholders.  Is a country an institution or an entity?  And who owns it, if it's an entity?

Comment: A business can also own shares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is a country an institution or an entity?

Neither.

It's a [sovereign state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_state) (a "political entity", not an entity in the sense of a legal persona).

Comment: in some countries with a monarchy, the leader is the embodiment of the souvreign even. There were times where "state" and "monarch" were the same!